# progress time bar in cocos2d disappers after restart game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, progress-bar

I've created a quiz game, that implements a time bar. In the first play it's all right, but if, after gameover, the player tap "restart", the game goes on properly, but the time bar disappears!

Here my code from GameOverLayer to Game:

```
-(void) restart {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer node]];
}
```

Here the function to create a new question

```
-(void)creaDomanda{

    //bar
    CCProgressFromTo *to1 = [CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:MaxTime from:100 to:0];
    bar = [CCProgressTimer progressWithFile:@"barra.png"];
    bar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR;
    [bar setPosition:ccp(size.width - 250 , size.height - 18)];

    int randomValue =  (arc4random() % 4) + 1; 
    NSString *stringa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Domanda%i", randomValue];
    dictionary = [plistData objectForKey:stringa];
    domanda = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Titolo"];
    labelDomanda = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:domanda fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:24];
    labelDomanda.position =  ccp( size.width /2 , 400 );
    [self addChild: labelDomanda];
    int rispostaEsatta = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"Soluzione"] intValue];
    menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:nil];
    for (int i = 1; i<5;i++)
    {
        if(rispostaEsatta == i){
item = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:[dictionary valueForKey:
                                                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Risposta%i",i] ]
                                                       target:self selector:@selector(corretto)];
        }else{
            item = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:[dictionary valueForKey:
                                                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Risposta%i",i] ]
                                                       target:self selector:@selector(sbagliato)];
        }
        [menu addChild:item];
    }
//[..]
    [self addChild:menu];
    [self addChild:bar];
    [bar runAction:to1];
}
```

And here one of the correct/wrong method (similar) that after all, create a new question:

```
-(void)sbagliato{
    CCLOG(@"Sbagliato");

    if (menu) [self removeChild:menu cleanup:YES];
    if (labelDomanda) [self removeChild:labelDomanda cleanup:YES];
    if (bar) [self removeChild:bar cleanup:YES];

    labelRisultato = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Hai sbagliato!" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:24];
    [labelRisultato setColor:ccc3(255, 1, 1)];
    labelRisultato.position = ccp(size.width / 2, 280);

    [self addChild:labelRisultato];
    [self gameOver:2 punteggio:0];
    // Richiamiamo il metodo per eliminare la label dopo 0,3 secondi
    [self performSelector:@selector(eliminaLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    increment = increment - 20;
    [pointLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Punti: %i", increment]];

    // new question
    [self performSelector:@selector(creaDomanda) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

Can anyone explain to me please why when I restart the time bar desappers?
Thank You

Comment: off topic: it's entertaining to read italian code :)

Comment: also it's making me hungry! :D

Comment: Thank You! I've tryied to translate some variables to make the code more clear :) but thank you :)

Comment: and sorry for all my problems, but If I want to call a method (wrong answer) after the time is elapsed how can I do? Something like ' if (Time==0)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(sbagliato) withObject:nil];
    }' ? What I have to put instead of "Time"

Answer (score 1):

My best guess:

The CCProgressFromTo action is still running. Since it progresses down to 0, the CCProgressTimer eventually doesn't display any part of it anymore. This may continue even if you run another CCProgressFromTo action on the progress timer.

Solution: be sure to stop any running CCProgressFromTo actions before running another.

If that doesn't fix it, then I imagine the CCProgressTimer needs to be reset by setting percentage back to 100.

Comment: I'll try and I'll write the results. but why every time that a new question in generated the bar is reinitialized correctly and after a new restart this doesn't happen?

Comment: Sorry but It doens't fix it. This may be because every time a new question is generated, the method remove the previous bar and recreate a new bar, resetting the pecentage! I don't understand why all the other parts of (newquestion) work properly, but for this part is not the same!

Comment: Nothing seems to work for fix this issue. I've solved other issues related to the bar (zombie objects) but for this one nothing.. How can I try to debug? Why my bar works properly until I restart the game?